Unable to access SUSE Rancher GUI via hostname
I've got problem recently with SUSE Rancher installation.
I'm unable to access the Rancher dashboard using the hostname <IP_OF_LINUX_NODE>.sslip.io after installing SUSE RKE2 & Rancher on an openSUSE 15.6 VM hosted on an Ubuntu 22.04 server using libvirt/kvm/qemu stack.
Environment:

Host: Ubuntu 22.04
Virtualization: Libvirt/KVM/QEMU stack
Guest: openSUSE 15.6
Proxy: Company proxy
DNS server: company server (10.0.DDD.EEE)
Installation: SUSE RKE2 & Rancher (Helm chart, Rancher generated certs)

Steps Taken:

Created a new VM with virt-install.
Installed openSUSE 15.6 (firewalld disabled).
Set environment variables (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY) in ~/.bashrc:

export http_proxy=<my-proxy-address>
export https_proxy=<my-proxy-address>
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,10.20.40.0/24,10.42.0.0/16,10.43.0.0/16,cattle-system.svc,172.16.0.0/12,172.17.47.0/24,192.168.0.0/16,.svc,.cluster.local,.<company>.local,<ubuntu-host-name>.<company>.com,.sslip.io,rancher


Updated system: sudo zypper refresh && sudo zypper update && sudo reboot
Configured the same proxy settings for RKE2 according to https://docs.rke2.io/advanced#configuring-an-http-proxy.
Installed RKE2 from tarball: https://docs.rke2.io/install/methods#tarball.
Installed kubectl: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-linux.
Installed helm: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-script.
Followed Rancher installation guide via Helm chart (rancher-stable repository, Rancher generated certs): https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/install-upgrade-on-a-kubernetes-cluster#install-the-rancher-helm-chart.

Expected Behavior:
Rancher dashboard should be accessible at <IP_OF_LINUX_NODE>.sslip.io.
Actual Behavior:
curl -k https://<IP>.sslip.io
returns:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <IP>.sslip.io
Troubleshooting:

It's possible to access Rancher dashboard on 10.43.XX.YY (service rancher) and 10.42.0.CCC (pod rancher).
Command curl -vv -k -H "host: <IP>.sslip.io" https://<IP> -v returns expected JSON response.
Same steps on a VirtualBox VM (guest openSUSE, host Windows) allow access to Rancher dashboard via hostname from both host OS and guest OS.
Update: I tried also to setup Rancher using k3s and result is also the same as for RKE2.

Additional information:
Rancher ingress:
Name:             rancher
Labels:           app=rancher
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  chart=rancher-2.8.5
                  heritage=Helm
                  release=rancher
Namespace:        cattle-system
Address:          192.168.AAA.BBB
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  tls-rancher-ingress terminates 192.168.AAA.BBB.sslip.io
Rules:
  Host                     Path  Backends
  ----                     ----  --------
  192.168.AAA.BBB.sslip.io
                           /   rancher:80 (10.42.0.CCC:80)
Annotations:               cert-manager.io/issuer: rancher
                           cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: Issuer
                           field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:
                             [{"addresses":["192.168.AAA.BBB"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"cattle-system:rancher","ingressName":"cattle-system:rancher"...
                           meta.helm.sh/release-name: rancher
                           meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: cattle-system
                           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: 30
                           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 1800
                           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 1800
Events:                    <none>


My rancher service:
Name:                     rancher
Namespace:                cattle-system
Labels:                   app=rancher
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          chart=rancher-2.8.5
                          heritage=Helm
                          release=rancher
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: rancher
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: cattle-system
Selector:                 app=rancher
Type:                     ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.XXX.YYY
IPs:                      10.43.XXX.YYY
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.CCC:80
Port:                     https-internal  443/TCP
TargetPort:               444/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.CCC:444
Session Affinity:         None
Internal Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>


Question:
What could be causing this hostname resolution issue on the libvirt/kvm/qemu VM? How can I fix it?
Please let me know if you require any further details or logs for troubleshooting.
